# django tutorial part 2 template opening from default only

Tags: python-2.7, django-templates, pdb

My setting for `TEMPLATE_DIRS` is

```
PATH_PROJECT = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
                 os.path.join(PATH_PROJECT, 'mytemplates/'),
                 )
```

but the `base_site.html` opens from the default position only.
I tried to debug with PDB. but while trying to put break point in `django/conf/__init__.py`, pdb gives the message End Of File.
My base_site.html resides in correct folder.

Answer (score 0):

are you working on Django >= 1.4? In this case the settings file may reside in a subfolder, you should then write the following code:

```
PATH_PROJECT = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__),'..'))
TEMPLATE_DIRS = ( os.path.join(PATH_PROJECT, 'mytemplates/'), )
```

to check if TEMPLATE_DIRS contains the paths you want, open django shell

```
python manage.py shell
```

and write:

```
from django.conf import settings; print settings.TEMPLATE_DIRS
```

Comment: Sorry I found my mistake, I was not adding the admin sub folder in spite of a big reminder from tutorial.